# How to activate AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient?

Tags: objective-c

Audio Player starts only one track, but it is necessary that the Play button starts a greater number of tracks at once. The documentation says:

> You can play multiple sound files at the same time. Under the hood,
>   this module uses AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient to mix sounds on iOS.

How to activate AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient since the following code in the file, the application falls AppDelegate?

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h> 
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIWindow *window;
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient error:nil];
    return YES;
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't enough to `setCategory`. You must also `setActive`. You are not doing that.

Apple advises activating just before the category is actually needed, and deactivating afterward. If you need the session to be active all the time, activate it in `applicationDidBecomeActive`, as it can be deactivated when the app is deactivated.

Comment: So?
`- (void)pluginInitialize {
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient error:nil];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:nil];
}`